Why do some authors check for "$x \ne w$" in reductions from $A_{TM}$ to $E_{TM}$?
Def.:
$A_{TM} = \{<M, w> \mid M$ is a TM and $M$ accepts $w \}$
$E_{TM} = \{<M> \mid M$ is a TM and $L(M) = \emptyset\}$
I found that some authors (e.g. Sipser 2013, 3rd ed.) use an additional check of "$x \ne w$" in the reduction from $A_{TM}$ to $E_{TM}$.
In general the reduction is as follows:

Let $R$ be a decider for $E_{TM}$. Construct a new TM $S$ that decides $A_{TM}$:
$S = $ "On input $⟨M, w⟩$, an encoding of a TM $M$ and a string $w$,

Construct new TM $M'$ with
$M'=$ "On input $x$

If $x \ne w$, reject
If $x = w$, run $M$ on input $w$ and accept if $M$ does."


Run $R$ on input $⟨M_1⟩$
If $R$ accepts, reject; if $R$ rejects, accept."


For that to be a valid reduction we must ensure that $R$ accepts iff $L(M')=\emptyset$.
But this is also true, if we omit the line 1.1. "If $x \ne w$, reject"
Because, even if we omit that line, we get:
$$S \text{ rejects } <M,w> \iff R \text{ accepts } M' \iff L(M') = \emptyset \iff M \text{ rejects } w$$
and
$$S \text{ accepts } <M,w> \iff R \text{ rejects } M' \iff L(M') \ne \emptyset \iff L(M') = \Sigma^* \iff M \text{ accepts } w$$
I see the need for the line in other similiar reductions like $A_{TM}$ to $REGULAR_{TM}$ where it's usually like "if $x=0^n1^n$, accept", but here I'm quite lost.. In this lecture notes (https://www.khoury.northeastern.edu/home/vkp/390-fl07/Undecidability-Results.pdf), page 9, the step is omitted. My results from a quick internet survey are that it's 50/50..
Is this check only to reduce the accepted language to $\{w\}$ instead of $\Sigma^*$ and therefore (maybe) makes it easier to follow for the reader?.. Or is it required?
Thanks!

Edit: To clarify: I would not suggest to run $M$ on $x$ in $M'$ but to ignore $x$ and run $M$ on $w$. As $w$ is part of the construction of $M'$ that should be legal and possible, even though $w$ is not part of the input to $M'$.

So you are assuming towards contradiction that $E_{TM}$ is decidable and use that to conclude the decidability of $A_{TM}$  (and thus reaching a contradiction).
What you need to show is that $L(M') = \emptyset$ iff $M$ does not accept $w$. Note that by rejecting all inputs $x\neq w$, we get that the language of $M'$ being empty depends only on the behaviour of $M$ on $w$, which is what we're trying to achieve -- in a sense, we need to filter out all inputs that are not equal to $w$.
Now if you omit the check in 1.1, and simply run $M$ on $x$ for all $x$, then it could be the case that $M$ accepts some $x$ and at the same time does not accept $w$. In this case, $L(M')\neq \emptyset$, yet $M$ does not accept $w$, and so the reduction is not valid due to the fact that now $L(M')$ being empty does not depend only on the behaviour of $M$ on $w$.
Edit: If your suggestion is to ignore $x$, and run $M$ on $w$ instead. Then, this is a different reduction that works. As also here, it holds that $L(M')$ is empty only when $M$ does not accept $w$. In a sense, also here, you design $M'$ so that its emptiness depends only on the run of $M$ on $w$. To sump up, the check is not required, and perhaps it was suggested to be friendly enough as one of the first examples of reductions -- authors usually present "stronger" tricks when there is a need.

Thanks, but the important part is, that I would not run $M$ on $x$ but ignore $x$ and run $M$ on $w$ which is embedded in the definition of $M'$ - therefore I can rule out that something different is fed into $M$.
The author(s) also do this because in all examples I've seen, they check for $w \ne x$ but then they run $M$ on $w$ not on $x$ (even though $x=w$ at that point)

@halliba I edited the answer. Both reductions are valid.
